# How to expand a numpy vector n times into an 2d array with its own values

Tags: numpy

With numpy, say you have a vector like:

```
array([1, 2, 3])
```

How do you extend it n times with its own values? E.g.:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.tile`:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
N = 3

b = np.tile(a, (N,1))
```

or `numpy.vstack`:

```
N = 3
b = np.vstack([a]*N)
```

output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```